# Changing the default description for org-mode file links

Tags: org-mode

The following is a very common workflow for me

1. Open a dired buffer, and place cursor on a file.
2. Invoke `M-x org-store-link`.
3. Visit an org file (that's usually in the same directory), and type `C-c C-l RET` to insert the link.

This way, org-mode inserts a link like the following:

```
[[file:some-file.org][file:~/Dropbox/Work/some-file.org]]
```

which displays on the buffer like this:

```
file:~/Dropbox/Work/some-file.org
```

It seems silly that org would use a relative file name for the link's
address, but use a long absolute file name for the human-readable description.

I would like to change this automatically created description, so that
it always shows **just** the file name (no directories). In the
example above it would look like `some-file.org` or perhaps
`file:some-file.org`.

#### How can I customize the automatic description of links inserted with `C-c C-l RET`?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended workflow is the use <kbd>C-u C-c C-l</kbd> to insert a file link. That one will be relative to the current directory if possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, my question was a little misleading. I mean I only want to see the file name, not the relative path. Even if the file is faraway.

Comment: Still, upvoting because the C-u prefix is helpful here (even if it isn't perfect), and I didn't know about it.